# Popular tags view active class

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view which is a HTML list of the most popular tags in a specific vocabulary it is displayed as a block on a page of most recent news items. It is also displayed on each individual news item.

When it is displayed on the individual news item page I would like any tag that the news item has been tagged with and that also appears in the popular tags block to be highlighted by adding a css class called active.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: I find you question really hard to understand. Can you edit it to improve the clarity and then I'll see what I can do to help...

Comment: I have updated it, hopefully this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only method I can think of is to do it the template, but have a feeling there must be a better solution than this... But to do it this way:

Edit your view and under Advanced click on Theme: Information. This shows a list of template file names that would apply to your view. If you had a view called tags then creating a template file called **views-view-fields--tags.tpl.php** would be appropriate. After adding your template file (in your themes directory) click the Rescan template files button.

The standard template file looks like this:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
    <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
    <?php print $field->content; ?>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But if you changed it to this:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
<?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
<?php print $field->separator; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
<?php print $field->label_html; ?>
<?php 
$current = false;
if(arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) { // check if we are on a node page
    $node = node_load(arg(1)); // load the node
    $tag = strip_tags($field->content);
    foreach($node->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $term) { // loop over the tags attached to the node
        if($term['taxonomy_term']->name == $tag) { // there is a match
            $current = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if($current) {
    print '<span class="current">'.$field->content.'</span>'; // add a span with current class
} else {
    print $field->content; 
}
?>
<?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The disadvantage of this method it that code needs to run for each tag in the list, but it would achieve the desired result.

Comment: This solution does work, but like you said there must be a better way I've created a views handler plugin (see below) but again I have to load the node every time a term is rendered when I only want to load the node once.

Comment: At least the node will be cached so there won't be too much overhead from loading the same node multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

MY_MODULE.module

```
function MY_MODULE_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/includes',
  );
}
```

MY_MODULE.views.inc

```
function MY_MODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['taxonomy_term_data']['name']['field']['handler'] = 'MY_MODULE_views_handler_field_taxonomy_active';
}
```

MY_MODULE_views_handler_field_taxonomy_active.inc

```
class MY_MODULE_views_handler_field_taxonomy_active extends views_handler_field_taxonomy {

  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
     $form['active_class'] = array(
       '#title' => t('Add active class to term link'),
       '#description' => t('This allows you to add an active class to a link id the term exists on the current page.'),
       '#type' => 'checkbox',
       '#default_value' => !empty($this->options['active_class']),       
     );
    parent::options_form($form, $form_state);
  }

  function render_link($data, $values) {
    $tid = $this->get_value($values, 'tid');
    if (!empty($this->options['link_to_taxonomy']) && !empty($tid) && $data !== NULL && $data !== '') {
      $term = new stdClass();
      $term->tid = $tid;
      $term->vid = $this->get_value($values, 'vid');
      $term->vocabulary_machine_name = $values->{$this->aliases['vocabulary_machine_name']};
      $this->options['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
      $uri = entity_uri('taxonomy_term', $term);
      $this->options['alter']['path'] = $uri['path'];      
    }

    if (!empty($this->options['active_class']) && arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      $raw_terms = array();
      $node = entity_load_single('node', arg(1));
      $terms = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_tags');
      foreach($terms as $k => $v) {
        $raw_terms[] = $v['tid'];
      }

      if(in_array($tid, $raw_terms)){
       $this->options['alter']['link_class'] = 'active';       
      }
      else {
        $this->options['alter']['link_class'] = ''; 
      }
    }

    if (!empty($this->options['convert_spaces'])) {
      $data = str_replace(' ', '-', $data);
    }
    return $data;
  }
}
```